# How to set output values in user created functions in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to understand how to set an output value in a user created functions in postgres. So I made this simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()

    RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $return_value$
        DECLARE return_value BOOLEAN;
    BEGIN
        SET return_value = TRUE
    RETURN return_value;
END;
$return_value$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would like to understand why this spawns the error

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "return_value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) the assignment of values to variables is done using `:=` in PL/pgSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS BOOLEAN 
AS 
$return_value$
DECLARE 
  return_value BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  return_value := TRUE; --<< you are also missing a ; at the end
  RETURN return_value;
END;
$return_value$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There is also an SQL statement `SET`, but it sets database configuration parameters rather than assigning PL/pgSQL variables, which explains the error message.